# Aggregate a table by several columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate (consolidate) a table that resulted from using rbind to join several data frames. I need to consolidate the rows that have the same values in several columns and sum the count for these rows.

For simplification, I'm displaying a sample of the table.

```
    count  freq   cdr3nt        cdr3aa    v          d     j       VEnd DStart  DEnd  JStart
 1. 5344   0.160  TGGGTCAACTAA  CASSQRD   TRBV14    TRBD1  TRBJ2-1  18    -1     18     27  
 2. 245    0.022  TGGACTAATCAG  CAQSTRTT  TRBV27-1  TRBD2  TRBJ2-5  12    17     -1     19
 3. 120    0.010  TAGGGAGGC     CASTT     TRBV7-2   TRBD1  TRBJ1-5  10    19     -1     34
 4. 102    0.010  TGGACTAATCAG  CAQSTRTT  TRBV27-1  TRBD2  TRBJ2-5  12    17     -1     19
 5. 52     0.001  TGGGTCAACTAA  CASSQRD   TRBV14    TRBD1  TRBJ2-1  18    -1     18     27
 6. 51     0.001  TGCGGGAA      CGSSST    TRBV4-3   TRBD2  TRBJ1-3  27    10     26     24
```

If the columns for cdr3nt, cdr3aa, v, d, j, VEnd, DStart, DEnd, and JStart have the same values, the count values for those columns should be summed, and only one row be displayed with the information. In addition, I would need to recalculate the frequency values for the rows consolidated by dividing the resulting count by the total sum of the counts for the table.  The resulting table should look like this:

```
 count  freq   cdr3nt        cdr3aa    v          d     j       VEnd DStart  DEnd  JStart
 5396   0.18  TGGGTCAACTAA  CASSQRD   TRBV14    TRBD1  TRBJ2-1  18    -1     18     27  
 347    0.034 TGGACTAATCAG  CAQSTRTT  TRBV27-1  TRBD2  TRBJ2-5  12    17     -1     19
 120    0.010 TAGGGAGGC     CASTT     TRBV7-2   TRBD1  TRBJ1-5  10    19     -1     34
 51     0.001 TGCGGGAA      CGSSST    TRBV4-3   TRBD2  TRBJ1-3  27    10     26     24
```

Rows 1.and 5. were consolidated, as well as rows 2. and 4. Their counts were added and freq was recalculated.  In the real-life version, there may be more than two rows with the same values.

I started out with the following piece of code trying to use the aggregate function but ran into trouble right off the bat. I didn't even bother to do the new frequency calculation.

```
 samrep1 <- read.table("/Data/tables_merge/JB-3_R1.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
 samrep2 <- read.table("/Data/tables_merge/JB-3_R2.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
 samrep3 <- read.table("/Data/tables_merge/JB-3_R3.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
 samrep4 <- read.table("/Data/tables_merge/JB-3_R4.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")

 table2 <- rbind(samrep1, samrep2)
 table3  <- rbind(table2, samrep3)
 table4 <- rbind(table3, samrep4)

 agg_table <- aggregate(table4, by=list(table4$cdr3nt), FUN = sum)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the formula version of `aggregate` wrapped in `within` for *freq* calculation:

```
final_df <- do.call(rbind, list(samrep1, samrep2, samrep3, samrep4))

agg_df <- within(aggregate(count ~ cdr3nt + cdr3aa + v + d + j + VEnd + DStart + DEnd + JStart, 
                           data = final_df, 
                           FUN = length),
                 freq <- count / sum(count)
          )
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/ITEXD37550)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back.  I'll test the code you suggest.

Comment: It works well.   The only thing is that I changed "table1, table2... etc" in the list to include the samrep1, samrep2, samrep3, and samrep4.  The table2...etc. are cumulative data frames, so I'd be aggregating the content of each table progressively.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating multiple objects in the global env, we can read it in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- list.files(path = "/Data/tables_merge", pattern = "^JB-\\d+_R\\d+\\.txt",
           full.names = TRUE) %>%
       map_dfr(read.table, header = TRUE, sep="\t") %>%
        group_by(cdr3nt, cdr3aa, v, d, j, VEnd, DStart, DEnd, JStart) %>%
        summarise(Count = sum(count), freq = Count/sum(.$count))
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back.  I'll test the code you suggest.

Comment: This works too.  I just need to create a variable to store the resulting data frame as opposed to just displaying it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Orion11 Yes, I thought it would be very easy

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with package `dplyr` and function `group_by`, `summarize` where summarize will aggregate the values.

```
library(dplyr)

dta %>% mutate(total = sum(count)) %>% 
group_by(cdr3nt, cdr3aa, v, d, j, VEnd, DStart, DEnd, JStart) %>%
summarize(count_new = sum(count), freq = count_new/mean(total))
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back.  I'll test the code you suggest.

Comment: Is "dta" the variable that contains the original data before the actions operate on it?  I'm assuming it does. Thanks for your help.